# How do you get rid of Itching sole?

Tags: hygiene

For some reason or the other, when I wear one of my shoes, my sole itches a lot. I know I can always get rid of the insole of the shoe, but I am yet to find a way to stop the itching in my sole.

Then I sometimes have to get my shoes off, find dry leaves and rub them against my sole and that feels better.

How do you so that if needs be?

P.S. I am sensitive to Tickling.

Comment: Isn't the actual question what makes he soles itch?

Comment: It is, but I can get rid of the shoe sole. I suspect it has to be the leather it is made up of.

Comment: Consult a doctor also, itchiness can be due to some skin conditions. And before someone points out its a particular pair not all the shoes: the condition of the foot in that particular pair or the material the shoe is made of can aggravate a skin condition and cause itching.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try benadryl cream.  If it stops the itch then you know it's a reaction with the shoe insole and you'll just need to replace the insole.

If that doesn't work, try soaking your feet in a hot salt bath and then scrubbing the sole of your foot with a pumice stone.  This will remove any skin that is contributing (by being rough, or dead, etc)

If none of that works, and replacing the insole doesn't work... good luck!

Comment: "If none of that works, and replacing the insole doesn't work..." - Replace your feet

Comment: @Mr.Derpinthoughton: Very funny! Did you scratch your head for this?

Comment: Sure, I had to do some research in order to come up with this well-structured joke, I'm glad you noticed it ;)